# OpenCV : Showing numpy array as image without saving it first

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a 2D numpy array, which I want to display as an image with openCV. Is there any way to do so, without first saving the numpy array as a png file ?

I don't understand why when I run the following code :

```py
cv2.imshow("image1", myNumpyArray)
cv2.imwrite("myImage.png", myNumpyArray)
cv2.imshow("image2", cv2.imread("myImage.png")[:,:,0])
```

`image1` display a full black picture, when `image2` display my image correctly.

`myNumpyArray` and the output of the `cv2.imread()[:,:,0]` function have the same type (`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`)  and the same shape (28, 28).

Comment: `myNumpyArray` type should be `unit8` then

Comment: Oh okay, my array was of type int64. Adding `myNumpyArray.astype(np.uint8)` solved my problem.
Thanks a lot !